# How to separate last column from 2D-array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to separate 2D array in order to have last column and the rest separately. Those must be arrays both.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> l = [row[:-1] for row in a]
>>> r = [row[-1] for row in a]
>>> l
[[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
>>> r
[3, 6, 9]
```